# Auto line breaks in workbench

Tags: workbench, interface

I have been using Mathematica for a while and thought of using Worbench to structure my project better. However, moving my code from .nb-files to .m-files in a Workbench project does not really work, since unlike the Mathematica frontend Workbench does no line breaks.

Is there a way to enable auto line breaks in Wolfram Workbench? If not, how is one supposed to work with long expressions in Workbench?

Comment: Is this any help: [Does Eclipse have line-wrap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2846002) ?

Comment: Hmm, so it seems Workbench has no line wrap. And installing the word-wrap plugin for various versions of eclipse does not seem to work with workbench.

Comment: With some luck, some more Workbench-savvy members will come up with something useful.

Comment: "If not, how is one supposed to work with long expressions in Workbench?" — Since _Mathematica_ doesn't have well defined standards for indenting/linebreaks/etc., it's up to you to break the code at places which makes reading easy (I don't like the NB's linebreaks). Also, if you're using the WB to create and maintain packages, the focus should be on clarity and ease of reading (for long term purposes), so perhaps you could try to not have reaaly long expressions and instead break them down to constituent functions and chain them.

Answer (score 1):

[This plugin works for me](http://ahtik.com/blog/projects/eclipse-word-wrap/), just be careful with the steps:

1. Help -> "Install new software", enter update-site in Work with field: "http://ahtik.com/eclipse-update/"
2. "Word Wrap" item should appear in the name below, check it and press Finish.